# How can I iterate through a set specific properties of objects in an array of JSON-objects?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

In a Logic App, I have 2 arrays, which both is parsed to JSON `{"Name":{"type":"string"},"Id":{"type":"string"}}`

```
(Array 1)
[
   {"Id": 1, "Name": "A"},
   {"Id": 2, "Name": "B"},
   {"Id": 3, "Name": "C"},
   {"Id": 4, "Name": "D"},
   {"Id": 5, "Name": "E"}
]

(Array 2)
[
   {"Name": "A"},
   {"Name": "D"}
]
```

I have a For each loop, with `@body('Array_1')` as input. Inside the loop I first have a condition where I want to check something like

```
"expression": {
  "and": [
    {
      "not": {
        "contains": [
          "@body('Array_2')",
          "@items('Array_1')['Name']"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In other words, I want to see if certain names is not contained in `Array 2`

The expected result is that the condition should evaluate to "true" 3 times (for name="B", "C" and "E") but it evaluates to true in all of the checks (5).

How can I loop through an array and check on properties belonging to the item I'm iterating through?

Comment: Have you enable "Concurrency Control" and set the "Degree of Parallelism" to 1 in the "Settings" of your "For each" in your logic app ? If "Concurrency Control" was set as "off", it may lead to this problem as you mentioned.

Comment: I'll try that. 
The issue is that what I'm trying to achieve I'm doing somewhere else in the Logic App, getting the expected results, without changing the parameters you're talking about. Only difference is "Array 1" don't have a "Id" property, leaving me to believe I'm accessing the properties of the objects in "Array 1" wrongly. 
Edit: Tried it. Unfortunately, same errors and it took way longer to fail.

Comment: Hi Anders, I have post the solution in the answer area, please have a try. If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to my "For each" in logic app show as below:
[image]

The "fx string()" is:
[image]

And the second box of "Condition" is:
[image]

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution!
I found my issue. My arrays was actually inside a JSON object like {"body":[...]}, but I thought that when using the "body" expression inside Logic App I would directly access the arrays inside of the body "key", which is not the case. 
The solution was to iterate over body('Array_1')['body'] and to use body('Array_2')['body'] in the expression.
Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @AndersKnudsen, I'm glad to hear that. I thought your json is in array but not in object, so I transform Array_2 to string in my logic app to judge if contains the "name" in Array_1. Anyway it's the best result, cheers~